# Why does my JavaScript object get converted to a string by returning it?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to load some csv data into a JS object. It loads the data converts it to an object and everything is fine within my converting function, but when I try to access it outside the function it appears to be a string and is no longer a JS object.

```
async function loadData() {
    let data = $.get("./p1.csv", function(csv){
        var lines = csv.split("\n");
        var result = [];
        var headers = lines[0].split(",");

        for(var i=1; i<lines.length; i++){
            var obj = {};
            var currentline = lines[i].split(",");

            for(var j=0; j<headers.length; j++){
                obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
            }

            result.push(obj);
        }
        console.log("1", result)
        return result; 
    });
    console.log("2", await data)
    return await data;
}
```

I expect the two print statements to return the same content but they don't. 
[Chrome dev tools output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuDap.png)

SOLVED

Changing the function to the following solves it:

```
async function loadData() {
    let data = $.get("./p1.csv").then(function(csv){
        var lines = csv.split("\n");
        var result = [];
        var headers = lines[0].split(",");

        for(var i=1; i<lines.length; i++){
            var obj = {};
            var currentline = lines[i].split(",");

            for(var j=0; j<headers.length; j++){
                obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
            }

            result.push(obj);
        }
        console.log("1", result)
        return result; 
    });
    console.log("2", await data)
    return await data;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps that's because Promise returned by `$.get` is resolved with the raw response, and not the result of `success` function? What happens when you transform it into `let data = $.get(...).then(function(csv) {... })`?

Comment: Your second log looks like the CSV

Comment: you're trying to return `result` from a callback. Why not use await all the way through?

Comment: I am willing to bet that you can not return from jQuery's onSuccess method since it was not designed to be returned from.

Comment: @raina77ow Thanks this solved it. Wow I spent way too much time on this.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to return from a callback which does not work in `JavaScript`. Use `async/await` all the way through:

This statement `return await data` in your code is equivalent to

```
let data = $.get("./p1.csv")
return await data; // <-- this returns your raw csv data as string
```

```
async function loadData() {
  let csv = await $.get("./p1.csv");
  var lines = csv.split("\n");
  var result = [];
  var headers = lines[0].split(",");

  for(var i=1; i<lines.length; i++){
    var obj = {};
    var currentline = lines[i].split(",");

    for(var j=0; j<headers.length; j++){
      obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
    }

    result.push(obj);
  }
  console.log("1", result)
  return result; 
}
```